# Error at line 14: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I keep getting the error below and I can't figure out why. I've included the tables in the code and then also the code portion that is presenting the error.

**Tables in the code:**

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    emp_id number(8) primary key,
    f_name VarChar2(20),
    l_name VarChar2(20),
    address VarChar2(40),
    city VarChar2(20),
    state Char(2),
    zip Number(5),
    phone_Number Number(10),
    email_address VarChar2(30),
    dept_id number(8) references department(Dept_ID),
    office_location VarChar2(30)
);

CREATE TABLE audit_detail (
    audit_detail_id number(8) primary key,
    field varchar2(30),
    old_value varchar2(30),
    new_value varchar2(30)
);

CREATE TABLE audit_trail (
    audit_trail_id number(8) primary key,
    user_id number(8)references user_id_table(user_id),
    table_name VarChar2(25),
    process VarChar2(25),
    emp_id number(8)references employee(emp_id),
    timestamp Date
);

Create table Department (
    dept_id number(8) primary key,
    dept_name VarChar2(20) not null,
    dept_start_date date
);

create table user_id_table(
    user_id number(8) primary key,
    emp_id number(8) references Employee(emp_id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE audit_seq;
```

**This is the portion that is presenting the error, Specifically the elsif Deleting portion**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_employee 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON Employee
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    timestamp DATE;
    session_user number(8); 
BEGIN
    timestamp := SYSDATE;
    session_user := USERENV('SESSION_USER');
    IF INSERTING THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_trail VALUES
        (Audit_seq.NEXTVAL, session_user, 'Employee', 'INSERT', :new.emp_id, timestamp);
    ElSIF DELETING THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_trail Values
        (Audit_seq.NEXTVAL, session_user, 'Employee', 'DELETE', :old.emp_id, timestamp);
    Else
        INSERT INTO audit_trail
        Values(Audit_seq.NEXTVAL, session_user, 'Employee', 'UPDATE', :old.emp_id);
        IF UPDATING ('f_name') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_detail VALUES
            (Audit_seq.CURRVAL, 'f_name', :old.f_name, :new.f_name);
        ELSIF UPDATING('l_name') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_detail VALUES
            (Audit_seq.CURRVAL, 'l_name', :old.l_name, :new.l_name);
        ELSIF UPDATING('address') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_detail VALUES
            (Audit_seq.CURRVAL, 'address', :old.address, :new.address);
        ELSIF UPDATING('city') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_detail VALUES
            (Audit_seq.CURRVAL, 'city', :old.city, :new.city);
        ELSIF UPDATING('state') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_detail VALUES
            (Audit_seq.CURRVAL, 'state', :old.state, :new.state);
        ELSIF UPDATING('zip') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_detail VALUES
            (Audit_seq.CURRVAL, 'zip', :old.zip, :new.zip);
        ELSIF UPDATING('phone_Number') THEN
            INSERT INTO Audit_detail VALUES
            (Audit_seq.CURRVAL, 'phone_Number', :old.phone_number, :new.phone_number);
        ELSIF UPDATING('email_address') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_detail VALUES
            (Audit_seq.CURRVAL, 'email_address', :old.email_address, :new.email_address);
        ELSIF UPDATING('dept_id') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_detail VALUES
            (Audit_seq.CURRVAL, 'dept_id', :old.dept_id, :new.dept_id);
        ELSIF UPDATING('office_location') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_detail VALUES
            (Audit_seq.CURRVAL, 'office_location', :old.office_location, :new.office_location);

        End IF;
    End IF;
End;
/
```

Comment: `Error at line 14: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored` is most likely just part of the error message. Please post the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your else statement after the deleting has 5 columns whereas audit_trail has 6.

```
ElSIF DELETING THEN
    INSERT INTO audit_trail 
    Values ( Audit_seq.NEXTVAL, session_user, 'Employee'
           , 'DELETE', :old.emp_id, timestamp);
Else
    INSERT INTO audit_trail
    Values (Audit_seq.NEXTVAL, session_user, 'Employee'
           , 'UPDATE', :old.emp_id );
```

You're also referencing columns in lower case not upper, `UPDATING ('L_NAME')`. I'm not sure whether that would cause a problem.

You're doing a lot of implicit number to character conversion which will eventually catch you out and table_name in audit_trail should by 30 characters not 25. Why risk it?